# Limiting Cold Side Temperature on Peltier

Tags: current-limiting, peltier

I'm trying to cool my computer's CPU by sticking a peltier between the CPU and the heatsink, however I don't want to deal with preparing my motherboard and for condensation. Therefore I want to keep the cold side temperature to 50/70*F. How do I regulate the cold side temperature? Is it by limiting voltage or current?

Comment: The temperature will vary tremendously depending on the load, and ambient temperature. This is probably not possible without feedback.

Comment: In cooling mode the peltier behaves more or less linearly.  Current is proportional to voltage, so you regulate current by regulating voltage.  Peltiers respond best to constant current/voltage rather than PWM, so you'll have to embed a temperature sensor (or use the one built into the cpu) and regulate the voltage provided to the peltier accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
To do so all that is needed is an automatic variable PWM circuit controlled by the voltage of a thermocouple, a small digital display can be used to set the desired temperature.
Explanation:
The system as a whole must have the capacity to run without overheating, i.e. - the heat output in watts of the item being cooled + the self-generated heat in watts of the Peltier module must be less than the heatsink/fan combination's capacity in watts to dissipate heat or the system will overheat. A Peltier module does not create cold, it cannot. It can only transfer heat. Its semiconductor properties allow it to transfer heat more efficiently by the addition of electrical current, adding its own heat while doing it. The heatsink draws this heat away from the module and transfers it into either a gas(i.e. - the atmosphere via heatsink air current) or liquid(i.e - a water block with circulating cool water) that can absorb the heat. The hot side of the Peltier must be in contact with an energy dissipation device that has a greater dissipating capacity(in watts) than the heat being generated(in watts) by what is being cooled that is in contact with the cold side of the Peltier module + the Resistive heat of the Peltier module itself. if the system does not meet these requirements, the system will fail.

Comment: I had originally wanted to avoid 'traditional' routes of PC cooling because liquid and anything around that route scares me. Plus, I had never seen anybody publish information on this (probably because it's unfeasible).

Just in case I do pursue these routes, are there any ways to get these sort of insulating materials off of my components? (silicone, dielectric grease, etc)
If dielectric grease is a GREASE, can I use brake clean on it? Will that damage the components?

Comment: I have cooled CPUs using both direct contact cooling with Peltier modules as well as using a water block to cool the CPU with the circulating water cooled to well below room temperature using Peltier modules(and fans etc. of course.) Case or atmospheric humidity is the enemy whenever you cool anything electronic using temperatures below the ambient temperature. If you need to clean thermal grease off of something, find out what is in it and use a solvent that will dissolve it. Always use a small amount of solvent on a cloth or paper towel, never pour or spray liquid onto electronic components.

Answer (score 1):

First, Peltier does not cool, it just creates a temperature differential between its two sides.

Peltiers aren't that good at carrying a lot of heat transfer.

Yes Peltiers can get pretty cold, but you cannot load much heat energy onto it, hence you won't be able to cool down your CPU much once it is running.

It is even reported that simple air cooling with the traditional radiator is more effective than using a Peltier, the reason being is that the power you use to drive the Peltier is also generating heat on the system by simple laws of physics..

> Would a Peltier plate be an efficient CPU/GPU cooler ?
>
> Not really. All it would do is move heat from the cold side of the
> Peltier to the hot side. You still have to remove the heat to the
> environment somehow.
>
> Further, Peltier cells are not 100% efficient, they take power to
> work, which ADDS to the head on the hot side. Moving 100 watts of heat
> might take 50 watts of extra input to the Peltier, giving you 150
> watts of heat to remove from the hot side.
>
> It is substantially more efficient to have a big heat sink and fan, or
> a heat pipe arrangement to move the heat out to where you have space
> for a big heat sink and fan.

From [Here](https://www.quora.com/Would-a-Peltier-plate-be-an-efficient-CPU-GPU-cooler-with-the-regular-cooler-on-top-of-cooling-the-hot-side)

Let's say your CPU needs to dissipate 60W of heat.

Let's say you get a 40W Peltier.

Some simple maths: 60+40 = 100W.

You just added another 40W to your system that you have to dissipate. You need a bigger cooler, bigger fan, that perhaps would have performed as well without peltier at all.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of cooling is described by equation (1). What it means to you is the more current (\$I^2\$) you run through the peltier, the more heating you will get. If you're trying to cool things down, then don't use full current. The efficiency is also determined by how much of a temperature gradient (temperature from hot to cold side) and the temperature of the peltier.

[image]
Source: https://www.electronics-cooling.com/2008/08/a-simple-method-to-estimate-the-physical-characteristics-of-a-thermoelectric-cooler-from-vendor-datasheets/

> How do I regulate the cold side temperature?

First you'll need a way to monitor the temperature, and a way to drive the peltier. Usually this is done with a control loop controlling the voltage (you could also control the power to the peltier but that doesn't work well for reasons I won't explain). Usually PID's are used to control the voltage, it can be done digitally or with analog electronics.

PWM can also be used to control the peltier, but is less efficient because it uses full current all the time and increases \$I^2R\$ losses from self heating.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful information about peltiers:

In cooling mode the peltier behaves more or less electrically linearly, meaning that the device is more or less purely resistive and current is directly proportional to voltage.  This lets you directly regulate current by regulating voltage.

The actual performance of the peltier is non-linear because of losses.  The amount of heat pumped rises proportional to current, but there are two forms of losses to account for.  First, resistive conduction losses, where a conductor is heated by the current passing through it.  The power lost here follows the formula:

\$P=I^2R\$

The power wasted varies with the *square* of current while the heat pumped varies with current.  This means as current rises, efficiency drops.

The second type of losses to worry about are thermal conduction/convection losses.  While you are using the peltier, aside from the thermal transfer caused by the peltier effect, the two plates of the peltier are held at a temperature difference, but remain connected by the little blocks of bismuth.  While heat is flowing one way with the charge carriers, it is constantly also flowing back due to regular thermal conduction through the bismuth blocks and conduction/convection through the air/gas between the plates.  Heat conduction is proportional to temperature difference and area of thermal conductor, so the larger the temperature difference or the larger the peltier, the more bleedback occurs.

Peltiers respond best to constant current/voltage rather than PWM because of the \$I^2R\$ losses.  If you run the peltier at two units of current and a 50% duty cycle, you get 2x the losses as if you ran it at one unit of current all the time.  If you ran ten units of current at a 10% duty cycle, you end up with 100x the losses.  The total amount of charge that flows and therefore the heat pumped is the same in all 3 examples.  A voltage/current regulator is basically a PWM driver with a filter on the output, so you still need PWM, but the filter that makes it a switching *voltage/current regulator* is crucial.

You'll have to embed a temperature sensor (or use the one built into the CPU) and regulate the voltage provided to the peltier accordingly.  You won't be able to get the CPU all the way to ambient either, because if it's at ambient, whatever is cooling it is below ambient and you have to worry about condensation.

In addition to the thermal load you are cooling with the peltier, it must be sized to pump all of it's own electrical and thermal conduction losses or it will not be able to achieve the desired thermal differential.  If the device is not sized large enough for even the load plus electrical losses, it will be unable to maintain a favorable temperature difference at all.  The hot side heat sink, similarly, must be sized based on load plus losses and also thermal difference between hot side and ambient.  How cold your cold side can get is limited by the thermal difference across the peltier and the hot side temperature, so you don't necessarily have many degrees above ambient on the hot side to work with.

Peltiers as a result perform better at low load and low thermal difference, and abysmally if they are not powerful enough.  This means if you're controlling it and reducing the applied voltage/current as well as the temperature gradient in your efforts to avoid condensation, it's an all around win.  The thing you really want to avoid is an inadequately sized peltier or cooler, as that will create waste heat from overdriving the peltier, or a large temperature differential and therefore waste heat(bleedback) from an inadequate cooler.  It's important to size the peltier based on the full output power of the CPU plus the thermal conduction losses of the peltier and to size the cooler based on this plus the full waste heat created by the peltier.

If everything is sized correctly, you should be able to simply achieve constant temperature under heavy load.  Run the peltier based on cold side or cpu temp and run the fan/water pump based on hot side temperature.

You'll have to convert this to American somehow, but I have a somewhat older 140W CPU in my system running with a factory made watercooling loop, bought on sale about the price of a good air cooler, and it hovers about 35-39\$^\circ\$C.  It really is a special use case to use a peltier if you're not looking for sub ambient temps.  Not necessarily a bad idea though, hope it works for you.

Comment: Peltiers are not linear devices, the Seebeck coefficient varies over temperature (the coefficient that determines how much heat is moved vs voltage), and they have self heating \$I^2R\$ heating from resistance.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Better I think if you wouldn't mind a look over.

Answer (score 0):

Peltier Modules can be accurately controlled using PWM, like many semiconductors, Peltier modules resistance changes with temperature complicating trying to control them using just current or voltage. PWM is not ideal, but far safer. Another alternative is an on/off circuit with on occurring at one temperature and off at another, basically a much longer pulse width. Using voltage to modulate a Peltier module is playing with fire. My 140-watt maximum draw AMD Opteron 6386SE CPUs rarely draw more than 100 watts even with all cores (32 or 16 per CPU)at an overclocked speed of 3.9 MHz. Stock, they are made to run at up to 3.2GHz with all 16 cores and 3.5 GHz using 1/2 the cores. Before including Peltier modules in my system, I used the larger of the two available sizes of Noctua Heatpipe air to air coolers and they rarely got above 30 deg. C. and never exceeded 40 deg. C. I used both thermocouples as well as in chip and onboard sensors using AIDA64 software for chip and board temps. I have 2x AMD Opteron 6386SE CPUs on a Supermicro H8DG6-F MOBO. It is one of very few boards that can Overclock Server CPUs. I solved my condensation problem by making a Peltier dehumidifier for my case and have my case fans set to maintain a positive case pressure with all inlet air passing through the dehumidifier that is on top of the case with exhaust fans at the bottom and circulating fans in the front blowing over HDDs using case air. The dehumidifier also slightly cools the case, temp, by about 2-3 deg.C. the greater than normal in case air currents also help with any condensation that might occur with stagnate air or a negative case pressure. I use OCNG bios replacement/altering software to gain control of my CPU, and FSB clocks and voltages as well as RAM settings. I did put high temp silicone "form-a-gasket" around my CPUs. More detail is out of the scope of this thread.

Comment: You already have a similar answer to this question from a few months ago.  You should combine them and delete one.  Driving peltier modules with PWM is highly inadvisable and modifying PWM drive into an appropriate buck regulator is a beginner level task so should not be neglected.  See my answer below.  Also, you'll get more votes if you break this answer into a few organised paragraphs or lists.  I can be bad for producing a wall of text sometimes myself, but you should try to fix this one.